# Running ProGuard on Apache Flink Application

Tags: proguard, apache-flink

I need to build an Apache Flink job for someone else to deploy. I would like to obfuscate the code using ProGuard, but just running it with the fat JAR as input throws me a shitload of errors, such as:

```
Note: scala.concurrent.forkjoin.LinkedTransferQueue$Node accesses a declared field 'waiter' dynamically
  Maybe this is program field 'akka.dispatch.forkjoin.LinkedTransferQueue$Node { java.lang.Thread waiter; }'
  Maybe this is program field 'org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.WaitingThread { java.lang.Thread waiter; }'
  Maybe this is program field 'scala.concurrent.forkjoin.LinkedTransferQueue$Node { java.lang.Thread waiter; }'
```

I already tried to exclude scala from obfuscation using:

```
-keep class scala.**
```

But it seems to be ignored by ProGuard. Does anyone have experience with such a setup and might be able to advise me? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to obfuscate the user-jar, or the Flink distribution? Or are you trying to setup a self-contained application that you can "just run" without any additional setup required?

Comment: I usually create a fat jar containing all the dependencies, which can be run from the command line as well as from within the Apache Flink Cluster Web Interface. I would like to obfuscate that one.